# Why is my Android emulator keyboard in Chinese character mode?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm debugging my Android application using the AVD (Android Virtual Device).  When I try to enter text in a text field, my characters are being interpreted as Chinese in the IME.

I don't know how I got into this mode or how to get out of it (I just want to enter alphabetic keys)?

Here's a screen shot:

[image: http://u.go2.me/3cn]

Answer (score 203, accepted):

If you were running [`monkey`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html) at some point, it probably changed the input method — it happens quite often.

You can change the input method by long-pressing on an input field and choosing Input Method → Android Keyboard.  I think you can also long-press on the bottom-left key on the virtual keyboard.

Note you can also disable the Japanese and other input methods from being activated entirely via Settings → Keyboard → untick the box next to each IME.

Comment: Can monkey run itself?  That would be pseudo-random indeed.  Based on the popularity of this question and answer, I'd say there was an erroneous default in the SDK.

Comment: @harpo: No, it can't run itself. There are no "defaults" that would cause `monkey` to run unless you explicitly start it. The only setting that causes this issue to happen is that the Japanese IME is enabled by default in the emulator, which isn't unreasonable.

Comment: I did not run monkey or anything like that but the "long-pressing on an input field" and choosing input method works! So thanks for the tip!

Comment: Didn't run monkey ever either, this is default emulator behavior upon creation (at least in certain versions).  Disabling the other IMEs did fix the problem though.

Answer (score 6):

I have a very simple trick..I found that..
Just go to the default browser provided in the emulator..then click on the address bar of the browser..
Magic....your language is now changed to English..

Answer (score 6):

Or you can just long press a

> `Text Field > Input Method > Android Keyboard`

See: [I cannot remove the Japanese IME from my Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724993/i-cannot-remove-the-japanese-ime-from-my-android-emulator)

Answer (score 2):

For emulator you can run such two commands to remove Pinyin IME (so latin would become default):

> > `adb shell`
>
> # `mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system`
>
> # `rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk`

the same, but easier to put into Jenkins:

> > `adb shell mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system`
>
> > `adb shell rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk`

You can first check which device is mounted to /system by running

> # `mount`

in adb shell.

If you need to remove another IME - just change a filename in "rm" command.

## Note: this will remove Pinyin IME completely. While you're not completely sure - don't do it on real devices as it would be hard to bring that IME back :)

Answer (score 0):

### **My Answer was simple**: `Changing Keyboard & Input Methods to English` and `Language English`

[image]