# Android Emulator Has Chinese Characters

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently started using eclipse and an AVD emulator to develop android apps for a droid.  Everything is going fine, except when i type in the emulator it returns chinese characters.  My location is set to en-us, so not sure what is going on.

Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Android emulator keyboard in Japanese character mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-japanese-character-mode)

Comment: similar question [Why is my Android emulator keyboard in Chinese character mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-chinese-character-mode)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can change the input method by long-pressing on an input field and choosing Input Method → Android Keyboard. you can also long-press on the bottom-left key on the virtual keyboard.

Comment: Also, Settings > Language & keyboard should show options for Chinese and Japanese IMEs, which you can uncheck to disable them.

Comment: Commonsware hit it on the head. My emulator is set to Japanese by default from the factory!

Answer (score 0):

You can run such two commands to remove Pinyin IME (so latin would become default):

```
> adb shell

# mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

# rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk
```

the same, but easier to put into Jenkins:

```
> adb shell mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

> adb shell rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk
```

You can first check which device is mounted to /system by running

```
# mount
```

in adb shell.

If you need to remove another IME - just change a filename in "rm" command.
Note: this will remove Pinyin IME completely. While you're not completely sure - don't do it on real devices as it would be hard to bring that IME back :)