# Android Gesture Builder displays Mandarin/Japanese characters?

Tags: android, gestures

Why does Gesture Builder pop up with Mandarin/Japanese predictive text when entering the name of a gesture, and then subsequently save that name in this language. Please help me set it back to English? all the dialogue on screen apart from that is in English???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds similar to this answer:
[Why is my Android emulator keyboard in Chinese character mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-japanese-character-mode/2268256#2268256)