# eclipse - stuck with chinese in android virtual device

Tags: android

When I run my android emulator in eclipse, all my keyboard characters gets translated to chinese when I try to write text. Why is this?

Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this previous question & answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-chinese-character-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Tap & hold on an `EditText`
2. Select **Input Method**
3. Select **Android Keyboard**

Comment: My AVD does the same, only this solution doesn't work. Tap and hold tells me that there is nothing to paste.

Answer (score 1):

For emulator you can run such two commands to remove Pinyin IME (so latin would become default):

```
> adb shell

# mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

# rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk
```

the same, but easier to put into Jenkins:

```
> adb shell mount -rw -o remount /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system

> adb shell rm /system/app/PinyinIME.apk
```

You can first check which device is mounted to /system by running

```
# mount
```

in adb shell.

If you need to remove another IME - just change a filename in "rm" command.

## Note: this will remove Pinyin IME completely. While you're not completely sure - don't do it on real devices as it would be hard to bring that IME back :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it gets translated to Chinese? From home screen, press Menu, Settings, Language and Keyboard..maybe you can tweak the settings there?