# My Android Virtual Device is broken

Tags: android, adt, android-virtual-device

The boss noticed that my app doesn't work on his 4.1 device, so I tried it out on a 3.0 (we agreed to have API level 11 as minimum) AVD and yes, there were issues but more with the AVD itself after fixing the class not found stuff.

- the AVD started in landscape
- the keyboard was in chinese (with [eclipse - stuck with chinese in android virtual device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361946/eclipse-stuck-with-chinese-in-android-virtual-device) 's solution not working)
- the contacts app crashes (yeah, I need a contact for my app but I can trick that as opening in incoming emulated sms allows me to edit the contact of that sender)
- dragging apps to the home screen locks up the phone
- even maps.google.com does not work in the browser
- the homescreen menu does not work (at all. The buttons show but no matter which one I click, it just doesn't do anything)
- … and yeah, there are issues with my app, but how can I assume they are related to my app and not to the totally borked avd?

If these symptoms ring a bell, please let me know as I'm kind of stranded. I already wiped ADT from my Eclipse and ~/.android from my file system and installed all newly to no success.

Edit:
Many of these bugs also appear in 3.2 although 3.2 is not landscaped.
4.2.2 works "fine". It only took 2 minutes to open the apps screen but on the first boot I won't complain.

Comment: Did you deleted the platforms too?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. I moved the whole SDK folder to a backup and after that I had to newly download the different API levels.