# How do I change the default keyboard input language in EditText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I think this is because my OS is in Chinese. I have an EditText box in my android app, and when I click on it to input something, the default input languange is in Chinese. Can I change it to Engish?

It seems because the project was created on my computer, when others import the project and run it on the emulator, the default input is also Chinese. Can I modify some file to change the **default** back to English? Many thanks!

The version I created the project in is Android 2.1

Answer (score 0):

Click and hold on the EditText. A context menu will appear that will allow you to change the IME (editor).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to get English input back to default?

Answer (score 0):

According to [My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-switch-or-change-input-method-on-android-smart-phone-device/):

> Alternatively, on Android keyboard or other input method which based
> on Android keyboard, tap and hold the ?123 key, and the keyboard
> settings dialog with option to switch input method will be displayed
> for selection.
>
> For the change of input method to take effect, unfocus
> the text input field (tap anywhere else) so that the keyboard closes,
> and then tap the input field again to open the new input method.

Comment: Thank you as well. But what I really want to do is to change the default to English. Is there a way?

Comment: Do u wish to change your language in emulator or on your device?

Comment: Please do not copy the words of others without proper citation. This is plagiarism, and we will not stand for it here.

Answer (score 0):

By default, all emulators have the Keyboards for English, Japanese IME and Chinese installed. Since the keyboard that is used by Android OS is a user's choice, there is no way to force using a specific keyboard in the app code. If you want to get rid of the unnecessary keyboards in the emulator completely, see the following post: [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-chinese-character-mode)