# Android Multi language Application

Tags: android, registration, multilingual

[Please See this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo4bn.png)

An android application with 2 languages ENGLISH and ARABIC, there is also a registration activity which includes Password and Email . So when application is in Arabic Language I want to keep password and Email in English language.
  Is there any solution for it?

I Just want to make EMAIL and PAssword in ENGLISH if locale is Arabic .

Comment: Keep separate string for every element in string.xml file.

Comment: Put Strings in only english language for email and password.

Comment: if a string is only in 1 string.xml file it throws Error , but we can keep the string in english in arabic string.xml file

Comment: everything is working perfect, just need to make EMAIL and PASSWORD EDITTEXT to keep in ENGLISH.

Comment: see my update......

Comment: GOT the Solution ,Thanks Everyon\e

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595440/multilingual-android-app-display-english-keyboard-in-email-password-fields

Answer (score 2):

This concept is called **Localization**. To provide localization support in app, you need to create different values folders in `res` directory.

What you need to do is, create folder structures with having strings.xml file in each folder.

```
values
   strings.xml
values-ar
   strings.xml
```

In each strings.xml file, declare a string with same key name but put values in languages accordingly.

Comment: everything is working perfect, just need to make EMAIL and PASSWORD EDITTEXT to keep in ENGLISH.

Comment: yes if you want it in english even in arabic values file then you can do that.

Comment: will it also work for EDitText fields? Please see Image above

Comment: you just need to set editText input type to email and password then use an english keyboard to type. You can check locality when submit button is pressed for validation.

Comment: yes English keyboard is a problem if USer have Arabic keyboard!

Answer (score 1):

**I hope you have created separate `string.xml` file for Arabic and English**

under `valuse-ar` create `string.xml` file add add this lines

```
<string name="email">EMAIL</string>
<string name="password">PASSWORD</string>
```

**UPDATE**

in your layout.xml

```
<Editext
........
.......
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 1234567890"
......
/>
```

this will allow only **numbers** and **english**
 letters

Comment: Please see image ,

Comment: what if keyboard is in Arabic , it wont type anything

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution here:
[Multilingual Android app: Display English keyboard in Email & Password fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595440/multilingual-android-app-display-english-keyboard-in-email-password-fields)

just add  android:imeOptions="flagForceAscii"

Answer (score 0):

try this tutorial

**Android Building Multi-Language Supported App**

[image]

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/

Answer (score 0):

You can use **translatable** property in **strings.xml**

```
<string name="email" translatable="false">Email</string>
```