# I cannot remove the Japanese IME from my Android emulator

Tags: android, keyboard, locale

I've seen this question many times but the answer is always "uncheck the IME from the 'Language & Keyboard Settings' menu.  The problem is that there's NO checkbox there.

Menu - Custom Locale - en_US is selected.

Menu - Settings - Language & Keyboard - Select Language - 'English (United States)' is selected.

Menu - Settings - Language & Keyboard - Japanese IME is the only IME and there is no check box to remove it.

I've also put a cursor into an editview and tried messing with the keyboard options visible while typing.  How the heck do I get English to show up?  This used to work fine before an unfortunate reinstall.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Long press a Text Field > Input Method > Android Keyboard

Comment: Sheesh, I can't believe I hadn't tried that.  Sorry for this dumb question!