# How to update or refresh the list view if the user changes value in edit text in android in getview method

Tags: android

How do I update or refresh the `ListView` if the user changes the value  in `EditText` in Android in the `getView()` method?
I am populating a list view data using a hash map using a custom adapter.
I am validating `EditText` row some edit text no need focus. I am validating using a touch listener. I am validating for `EditText` to accept only numeric and decimal characters. In the `getView()` method in custom adapter calling textwatcher if the user changes the edit text value. I am updating hashmap and calling  `notifydatasetchange` in the `afterTextchange()` method in adapter class. If I call notifydatasetchange method keypad displays wrongly not able to give value in `EditText`?

Thanks

Comment: press back button and keypad will be gone. Keypad will not come when you will install your apk on mobile.

Comment: @Pain user should edit the value using keypad when i call notify datasetchange it is not editing

Comment: If it is this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-chinese-character-mode) will help.