# Unfortunately *Chinese Characters* Stopped error in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator

### I am getting this error message

[image]

---

### My Language settings is English(US)

[image]

---

### My Emulator Settings

[image]

---

### My Question::

***How can I resolve this error. This error keeps on popping up every time in random intervals***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-chinese-character-mode?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **My Answer was simple**: `Changing Keyboard & Input Methods to English`

[image]