# Android: Display English keyboard default

Tags: android, localization, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, multilingual

Android Kitkat:
**Can you give me some hints about the following question ?
Display always English keyboard for a specific edit text field:**

Question: 
•   How can I make sure the English language keyboard is always displayed when the user selects a specific Edit Text field in his tablet where the localization is set to Russian or Japanese or other language ? Basically override the Russian keyboard for a specific textfield

Answer (score 0):

> By default, all emulators have the Keyboards for English, Japanese IME
>   and Chinese installed. Since the keyboard that is used by Android OS
>   is a user's choice, there is no way to force using a specific keyboard
>   in the app code. If you want to get rid of the unnecessary keyboards
>   in the emulator completely, see the following post: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268239/why-is-my-android-emulator-keyboard-in-chinese-character-mode)

As [Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404433/christoph) said